# Kafka - Docker - Error when sending message from Host to Container (Batch Expired)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm having a difficult time troubleshooting, what should be a simple kafka-issue.

I'm trying to publish a few messages from `kafak-console-producer`.  When I type 'hi' I get:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test --broker-list 172.17.0.21:9092
hi
[2016-01-25 12:56:19,839] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: Batch Expired (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

I don't seem to be able to find any kafka-log4j-logs...

I'm running the kafka server the way it is described in the [quick-start](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_startserver)

I can create the topic & describe it.

One note which maybe important is that the kafka & zookeeper are running in a docker-container (`172.17.0.21`) I'm creating the topic and sending messages from the host.

---

Please note the both the (kafka-server) 9092 & (zk) 2181 are open and accessible from the host, I've confirmed this using netstat & telnet.

Comment: Which version of Kafka? Running a public Docker image or one that you built yourself? What's the `docker run` command that you're using to start the container? Have you altered the default Kafka configuration? Are you running ZK in a separate container?

Comment: @MarkoBonaci - this problem killed me but I learnt several valuable lessons.  It is my own docker image.  Posted an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turned out to be more of a Docker issue...

OK, when running the client `kafka-console-consumer.sh` I saw that it was trying to connect to the broker using the container's name (which is the first few characters of a GUID).

My host cannot resolve connecting to docker-container using host-name.

Since I had already mapped the ports to my host, I changed the kafak-server config's `advertised.host.name` to point to my host's IP address.

That way whenever zk is queried for the broker my host's IP address is returned, then through port forwarding I'm connected to the broker in docker.

Comment: Yes, `advertised.host.name` was my initial thought ([a common problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34494443/465710)), but I wanted to get more info before mentioning it.

Comment: Did you change this in your kafka-server config in your docker container?

Answer (score 2):

I am trying with kafka 0.10.0.0 in docker and found below

> advertised.host.name  DEPRECATED: only used when `advertised.listeners`
>   or `listeners` are not set. Use `advertised.listeners` instead.
>   Hostname to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. In IaaS
>   environments, this may need to be different from the interface to
>   which the broker binds. If this is not set, it will use the value for
>   `host.name` if configured. Otherwise it will use the value returned
>   from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().

so set advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://yourhost:9092 will work

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you know that you can set that variable from the `docker run` command, right?

E.g. this is how I start Kafka & ZK in a single container, for my local development environment:

```
docker run --name st-kafka -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 -e ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip machine_name` -e ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -d spotify/kafka
```

Then, to create a topic:

```
docker exec -ti st-kafka bash -c "/opt/kafka_*/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4 --topic topic_name"
```

That's on OS X, which is why I use `docker-machine ip MACHINE_NAME`.
As you can see, that's Spotify's image. Although there was no `v0.9` last time I checked, it's trivial to fork the `Dockerfile` and adjust for `0.9`.

Comment: thanks. I built my own image...I wasn't using spotify.